# how can I get a list of indexes of nodes that have a value using xpath

Tags: xpath

using the following;

```
    <a>
  <b>false</b> 
  <b>true</b> 
  <b>false</b> 
  <b>false</b> 
  <b>true</b> 
  </a>
```

I want to get the following result using something like
/a/b[.='true'].position()
for a result like
2,5 (as in a collection of the 2 positions)

Comment: ended up doing an xslt that slaps ID's on everything so this problem became trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I. XPath 1.0 solution**:

**Use**:

```
count(/*/*[.='true'][1]/preceding-sibling::*)+1
```

This produces the position of the first `b` element whose string value is "true":

```
2
```

Repeat the evaluation of a similar expression, where `[1]` is replaced by `[2]` ,..., etc, up to `count(/*/*[.='true'])`

**XSLT - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:for-each select="/*/*[.='true']">
    <xsl:variable name="vPos" select="position()"/>

    <xsl:value-of select=
     "count(/*/*[.='true'][$vPos]
               /preceding-sibling::*) +1"/>
    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
   </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<a>
    <b>false</b>
    <b>true</b>
    <b>false</b>
    <b>false</b>
    <b>true</b>
</a>
```

`The XPath expression is constructed and evaluated for every`b`, whose string value is`"true"`. The results of these evaluations are copied to the output`:

```
2
5
```

---

**II. XPath 2.0 solution:**

**Use**:

```
index-of(/*/*, 'true')
```

**XSLT 2.0 - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:sequence select="index-of(/*/*, 'true')"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this XSLT 2.0 transformation is applied on the same XML document (above), the XPath 2.0 expression is evaluated and the result of this evaluation is copied to the output**:

```
2 5
```

Answer (score 0):

A basic (& working) approach in [python](/questions/tagged/python) language :

```
from lxml import etree
root = etree.XML("""
<a>
  <b>false</b> 
  <b>true</b> 
  <b>false</b> 
  <b>false</b> 
  <b>true</b> 
</a>
""")

c = 0
lst = []

for i in root.xpath('/a/b/text()'):
    c+=1
    if i == 'true':
        lst.append(str(c))

print ",".join(lst)
```